# scrapy.core.scraper ERROR: Error downloading -- OSError: Errno 24 Too many open files

Tags: python, windows, scrapy

I inherited a scrapy application which crawls through several 1000 pages on a domain and writes the final results out to a json file.  The author had been running this on a mac and had encountered a limitation with OS where it complained the limit on open files had been reached.  He addressed this by overriding the upper limit at the os level:

> $ ulimit -n 2048

I am running this on windows, which apparently has no upper limit, but I am still encounter the same issue.  After scrapy runs for a bit it, it throws a bunch of errors like this and then gives up:

```
2023-11-17 14:30:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://some_page>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1445, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(g.send, result)
  File ".venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
  File ".venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\httpcache.py", line 77, in process_request
  File ".venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\httpcache.py", line 302, in retrieve_response
  File ".venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\httpcache.py", line 354, in _read_meta
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'path to file\\pickled_meta'
```

I've read this is a python issue and tried applying this fix, which was no help:

```
import win32file
win32file._setmaxstdio(2048)
```

At the moment, the cache shows that 63,744 files have been created.  So, I don't know if this is an OS problem, a python problem, some bug in scrapy or some misuse of it.  I can post some of the code here, but I don't know what would be relevant - the spider, the item pipeline, the parse method or the settings file.  Any ideas to try to address this would be appreciated.  Please let me know what other details I can provide.

Here are relevant project settings:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 16
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'pipelines.JsonWriterPipeline': 301
}
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0


def is_running_in_container():
   """Determines if we are running in a container"""
   cgroup_path = '/proc/1/cgroup'
   if not os.path.isfile(cgroup_path):
      return False

   with open(cgroup_path, 'r') as cgroup_file:
      for line in cgroup_file:
         parts = line.rstrip().split(":")
         if len(parts) < 3:
            return False
         if parts[2] != "/":
            return True

   return False


def get_httpcache_dir():
   """Returns the appropriate httpcache directory to use
      depending on envrionment"""
   if is_running_in_container():
      parent_dir = "/scrapyd/scrapyd/data"
      if os.path.isdir(parent_dir):
         return f'{parent_dir}/httpcache'

      return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), "scrapy_httpcache")

   # Return a relative dir
   return 'httpcache'

HTTPCACHE_DIR = get_httpcache_dir()
HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []

# HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.DbmCacheStorage'
```

This is output from the log after the last run:

```
 023-11-18 12:50:51 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 4205141,
 'downloader/request_count': 9859,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 9859,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 418300317,
 'downloader/response_count': 8188,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 8188,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 701,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 12209.725667,
 'finish_reason': 'shutdown',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 18, 17, 50, 51, 249912, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'httpcache/firsthand': 9859,
 'httpcache/miss': 9859,
 'httpcache/store': 9859,
 'item_scraped_count': 7763,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1671,
 'log_count/INFO': 228,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 8188,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 9859,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 9859,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 9859,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 9859,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 18, 14, 27, 21, 524245, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
```

Adding the pipeline code here:

```
class JsonWriterPipeline:
    """Use to save items to JSON files"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = None
        self.logging: Final = logging.getLogger('jsonwriter')
        self.fileName: Final = 'items.json'

        # counter of number of scrapes read in so far, used to provide some helpful debug later
        self.recordsScraped = 0

    def open_spider(self, _):
        """Callback called when a spider is opened"""
        self.file = open(self.fileName, 'w')

    def close_spider(self, _):
        """Callback called when a spider is closed"""
        self.file.close()
        if self.recordsScraped > 0:
            self.logging.info(f'Wrote {self.recordsScraped} records to file: {self.fileName}')

    def process_item(self, item, _):
        """Use to save an item yielded from a spider in a JSON file"""
        line = json.dumps(ItemAdapter(item).asdict()) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        self.recordsScraped += 1
        return item
```

Comment: Is it supposed to create that many files?

Comment: @Alexander that seems to be the default behavior in scrapy, it creates 6 files per source and there's a lot of pages were crawling.  It seems weird though that the application would hold each file open rather than just close them after reading / writing.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Does your project have additional settings related to httpcache? I looked into FilesystemCacheStore source code more deeply and I think scrapy really can.. left files opened in case if `HTTPCACHE_GZIP = True` applied  to settings (by default it's `False`. (If possible - append output of "Overridden settings" log entry into question)

Comment: @Georgiy I have added settings and some of the stats from the last run.  There are settings to run in a container, but we are not using it.  Please let me know if there's anything else I can add

Comment: I think we are going to need a [mre] in order to fully debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application use httpcache to store received responses.
By default `scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage` applied if httpcache enabled.

> At the moment, the cache shows that 63,744 files have been created. So, I don't know if this is an OS problem, a python problem, some bug in scrapy or some misuse of it. I can post some of the code here, but I don't know what would be relevant - the spider, the item pipeline, the parse method or the settings file.

For each stored response `FilesystemCacheStorage` create 6 files and 1 folder.
[source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/f2fb4760d2e98cc92ab00a84bcf20cd8a6de3799/scrapy/extensions/httpcache.py#L317-L340)

I'd recommend You to apply dbm based cache storage by applying

```
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = "scrapy.extensions.httpcache.DbmCacheStorage"
```

to proj settings (It create only few files - it's source on the same link)

However in my practice I didn't have issues with `FilesystemCacheStorage` on that amount of files.

Comment: I deleted the cache and tried this setting, it seemed to only create a couple of files - one of which was `<spider>.db.dat`  It eventually threw the same error, too many open files, referring back to the dat file.  I wonder if this error message might be about something else.

Comment: For me it's not clear how spider managed to open dbm based cache storage, and store 9859 responses. If application failed to open `<spider>.db.dat` with too many opened files error - then spider should.. not cache any item. While on stats we see - `'httpcache/store': 9859` and `'log_count/ERROR': 1671` (errors have.. other origin). So for me it is clear that it is not scrapy issue. Or it is caused by some custom code (I'd  recheck custom json pipeline code) or it is something else.

Comment: The pipeline code looks straight from the template to me, but I'll add it to the question.  I tried running with the cache turned off and now I am getting the too many files error on the `<spider>.log` file, but no cache files were created and only the item.json seemed to be written to

Comment: Then it is 100% not scrapy issue. It is something else. I am not able to reproduce this locally using existing ifno.